# isset giving unexpected results when two conditions are given

Tags: php

Can someone please assist. If I do my code as below it works perfectly well,

```
 if (empty($error_message) && !isset($_POST["subject1"])){

                    $error_message = 'Invalid form input! Please select at 
                     least one option';
                  }
```

But once I add another condition like below it gives me unexpected behavior??

```
     if (empty($error_message) && !isset($_POST["subject1"], 
                                         $_POST["subject2"])){

                    $error_message = 'Invalid form input! Please select at 
                     least one option';

                  }
```

Comment: isset returns true only if both vars set

Comment: what is unexpected behavior?did you check the values of these individual $_POST values? show us values of `$error_message,$_POST["subject1"], and $_POST["subject2"])` ? echo them and show us

Comment: @Fast Snail. Both are set hence I don't expect the code to be executed BUT if only one is set as in the first code the code is not executing and that's the behaviour I am expecting also on the second code.

Comment: @Fast Snail. Here they are: Array
(
    [subject1] => Maths
    [subject2] => Art
)

Comment: `var_dump(isset($_POST["subject1"],$_POST["subject2"]))` what do you see?

Comment: @Fast Snail. bool(true)

Comment: that's weird `!isset($_POST["subject1"], $_POST["subject2"])` must be false so if shoudn't execute

Comment: Add a small, reproducible example within a complete .php file.